# Android. Кадровая анимация. Ошибка при превышении 13 кадров

Tags: android

Непонятная ситуация. Сначала вылетала ошибка (в реальном телефоне) при попытке сделать кадровую анимацию и изображений размером 1280 пикс. Уменьшил их до 600 заработало, но при превышении 12-13 кадров в анимации - приложение приостанавливается и завершается. В чем может быть дело ? Даже проигрыш кадров выносил в отдельный поток - приложение не вылетает но анимации нет (белый фон). Анимация представлена средствами XML :

```
 img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bglayout);
        AnimationDrawable myAnim = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
        myAnim.start();
```

---

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0000"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0001"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0002"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0003"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0004"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0005"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0006"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0007"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0008"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0009"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0010"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0011"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0012"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0013"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0014"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0015"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0016"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0017"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0018"/>
    <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/vbg0019"/>
</animation-list>
```

Comment: А с какой ошибкой вылетает? С нехваткой памяти? Мне когдато в похожей ситуации помогло написание своего аниматора на основе таймера.

Comment: не знаю, я настолько еще не обладаю знаниями по отладке. Но телефон у меня Galaxy s5, должен был теоритичесски вроде как работать

Comment: В общем. Прочитать логу,  сделать изображения код разные экраны  mdpi xdpi и так далее. Если проблема останется задуматься о кастомных библиотеках.

Comment: Если коротко, то нельзя использовать так DrawableAnimation. Вам просто нужно написать кастомный свитчер картинок с таймером, чтоб оно не висело в памяти. Да и вы не можете анимацию вынести в отдельный поток, как вы писали выше.
А в целом кончено у вас OutOfMemory, и стоит это указать в вопросе.